# weird behaviour or misunderstanding of laravel relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-8

weird behavior or misunderstanding of Laravel relations.
I have got a Product model. I getting products with translations and its category.
I have defined relations in both models.
I can access the data in the model or in the controller. but in view It says non-object.

```
Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object (View:
```

https://flareapp.io/share/LPdxbvvP - error.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

and here is a weird part.
[image]
as you can see here when I do display the category relation out using {{}}. it gives JSON string.

Where did I mess up?!

Comment: The problem might be your some data is null.

Comment: Check your data to make sure it's not null.

Comment: thanks to all of you I understood, Sok chanty mentioned I had to handle the case where some relation data is null.

Answer (score -1):

guys, I am so sorry about this. I didn't think of the category relation data can be null. in that case, it does throw an error. The simple solution is this.

> ```
> {{$item->category->slug ?? '-'}}
> ```

Comment: why do you think so? the problem was with null data coming from relations. so this is the answer to what I asked for.